# Adding a tool bar to visual studio 2010 - windows from application

Tags: asp.net

i just downloaded an RSS Toolkit for .net.

where do i need to place it? in which folder so it will become available on my 
visual toolbars?

and what types of files do i need to place in this folders? is it the *.dll only or more?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(DLL) that can be either placed in GAC or in ‘bin’ directory of a web site application.

If the ASP.NET application consumes RSS feeds, the trust level must be configured to allow outbound HTTP requests.
To take advantage of disk caching, there must be a directory (configurable via AppSettings["rssTempDir"]) where the trust level policy would allow write access. However, disk caching is optional.